# compare time() with timestamp

Tags: php, timestamp

Currently I'm storing timestamps in the database like such `1378852898`

How can I check this against the current `time()` to see if it's within the last 10mins with PHP?

Answer (score 0):

`if (time() - $timestampvar < 10 * 60) { ... }`.

Comment: trying to earn points

Comment: @vladkras: wrong guess. i submitted the answer before it was marked as duplicate. i am not aware that researching possible duplicates on SO is considered part of this site's etiquette.